# Git hook common to all repositories on my server machine

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks

How to configure a git server side hook that runs on every push to any repository on my gitlab server?

I have hosted gitlab locally on my machine and I want to run a script when any changes are made to any of my repository.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is too broad of a question. Please read through this before you post any more here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**git**](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.9.0.txt#L127-L128) (v2.9 and newer) supports specifying `core.hooksPath`
a common location where the git hooks scripts are stored.

1. Copy all the git hook scripts in to `<path-to-git-hooks-directory>`.
2. Specify a `hookspath` within the `.git/config` of the git repos pointing to the above directory.

   ```
   [core]
       hooksPath = <path-to-git-hooks-directory>
   ```

> Specifying `core.hooksPath` in the global git config (usually located at `~/.gitconfig`) will automatically set this common location containing the git hooks for ALL git repositories on the system by default.

More details [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks).

Comment: Thank you @TheCodeArtist :)

Answer (score 0):

You can store them in one place and create symbolic links in particular `.git/hooks` directories.

```
ln -s /path/to/myhooks/commit-msg project/.git/hooks/
```

See also TEMPLATE DIRECTORY in `git help init`  how to include hooks into a newly created repository.

Comment: I should create symbolic links in .git/hooks directory of all my repositories right?? But I want this hook to be common for all.

Comment: @VijayaLakshmi: Once you have created all the links, the hook will be common for all.

Comment: Also, if you have all the projects in the same directory, you can do something like `for project in */ ; do ln -s /path/to/commit-msg "$project"/.git/hooks ; done`.

Comment: Yes, I know. But In case of huge number of repositories what can we do? I should insert link into all my post-receive hook. right?

Comment: Thank you @choroba